# Sparkplug ground electrode burned off

Tags: sparkplugs

2010 Ford F-150 5.4 3valve did a tuneup changed sparkplugs and coils with correct Motorcraft plugs and AC Delco COP’s now I have burned off 2 ground electrodes in less than 100 miles. No codes on the computer or mis-fire information from my code reader. Used di-electric lube on COP boots and nickel anti-seize on the threads.
Should I go back to the original Ford COP’s?
I’ll have to add the image later as the one I have is too large of a file.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What was involved in the “tune up”?

Comment: Sounds like detonation to me.

Comment: Very impressive; Last I looked those electrodes are Inconel  - impervious to any gas mix in the combustion chamber and temperature up to 2000 F. So you are looking for something that would cause sustained or frequent electric arcs to produce very high temperature . Much higher energy that the normal spark. ( Judging from the third plug from the right side.) . I guess there is no chance that could have been the original condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Should not use anti-seize on the threads, just proper torques.
Loose spark plugs pull air into the combustion chamber and lean that cylinder. Replace the plugs and try again.
The loose plug can definitely burn the electrode off.